# C. T. Onions' Five Forms of the Predicates

Tags: vocabulary

> 3rd Form: The predicate consists of (1) a verb and (2) an object, which denotes the person or thing which the action of the verb ‘***passes over***.’
>
> –– [C. T. Onions](http://www.intcul.tohoku.ac.jp/ronshu/vol17/12.pdf)

What does ‘passes over’ mean?

Comment: In other words, affects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Pass* here is the second sense in [OALD](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/pass):

> **2** [<sub><sup>INTRANSITIVE</sup></sub>] + **adverb/preposition** to go or move in the direction mentioned
>    *The procession passed slowly along the street.
>
>    A plane passed low overhead.*

Onions puts 'passes over' in quotes for two reasons:

- because it is a literal translation of the common grammatical term *transitive*, from Latin *trans* = ‘across, over’ + *ire* = ‘to go, to pass’
- because the notion of the “action” of the verb “passing over”  its object is merely a metaphor for a grammatical relationship which is very difficult to put into words. How on earth do you describe *transitivity* in a manner which captures the very different relationships between the verb and its objects in these sentences?

  > StoneyB loves gooey butter cake.
  >   Ryan whacked his little sister.
  >   Listenever studies English grammar.

  Onions adopts the language of his classical predecessors while making an effort to acknowledge that the language is inadequate.

Answer (score 1):

I found a similar (though not identical) definition in [Google Book](http://books.google.co.th/books?id=FpUBFNFuKWgC&pg=PA27&lpg=PA27).

Under **Types of verbs**, it says

> Types of verbs: Transitive and intransitive verbs. Transitive verb is a verb which denotes an action which passes over from the subject to an object. The intransitive verb is a verb which denotes an action which does not pass over to an object or which expresses a state or being. For example, he ran a long distance.

The use of this *passes over* is similar to the definition "to leave out" in [the Free Online Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Pass).

> **pass over**: To leave out; disregard.

Having said that, it seems more like we could interpret *"passes over"* here (in both OP's quote and the above quote) simply as *pass* (verb) and *over* (preposition), i.e. **to pass an action over from the subject to an object**.

Comment: What you quoted is very helpful. But your interpretation I don't get much: 'the action of the verb disregards the person or thing'? I'd rather guess 'pass over' might be 'to go [affect] toward [the person or thing]'

Comment: Agreed. I wouldn't choose disregard myself too, but I think interpreting "passes over" as "to leave out" is passable. (Because it's the action that pass from the subject to an object.) To me, "act upon" might be a better choice, but I couldn't find that in the dictionary. --In my language, we simply say the subject acts upon the object. Much simpler, right?:)

Comment: That leads me to think that 'pass over' is not a two words phrase, but 'pass'(intransitive) plus 'over'(preposition) that takes 'the person or thing' as its complement.

Comment: Me too. The sentence would be perfectly understandable without "over". Should I choose other definition from "pass" in that dictionary instead?

Comment: @Listenever Right, "pass over" is not a phrase.  It is however an idiomatic combination of words, and **idioms need not be syntactic constituents**.  Idioms like these are often referred to as "phrasal verbs" even though they are not, in fact, phrases.

Comment: @snailboat I'm not sure that the notion of 'phrasal verb' isn't justified in this particular case, where Onions clearly intends it to translate L *transire*.